# Netscreen-Remote Equivalent On Linux

Tags: vpn, juniper, netscreen

We're running a simple Juniper VPN tunnel (using Juniper SSG5's) for outside-network access, which works great for Windows PCs since they can connect using the supplied Netscreen-Remote VPN client.

Has anyone successfully managed to get this working under Linux? There are several alternatives, but none seem to actually work. The following were tried, but failed:
- http://www.prolixium.com/netscreenlinux
- http://david.dw-perspective.org.uk/Juniper-Networks-SSL-VPN-Client-On-Linux.html

The official version is no Linux Client will ever be developed by Juniper themselves, but perhaps other (open) software exists that has been found compatible to Juniper's VPN?

Answer (score 1):

IME racoon can be made to work with ScreenOS/JunOS VPNs, but it's not trivial to setup.

I assume OpenSWAN and StrongSWAN should work too.

I think Cisco's VPN Client could work too, but its license requires that it be used with a Cisco device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [vpnc](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/)? Worked for me.

Comment: That page hasn't been updated since 2008.  Got any newer links?

Comment: Sorry; it was a while ago. I just installed it from my distro's packages. I think vpnc is integrated into newer versions of NetworkManager.